# search.php file not pointing where it should

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi I have I started to create my first wordpress template yesterday and today I have gotten to the point where I have to create the search page result.From what I found online that should be search.php file.But for some reason it seems Wordpress is not pointing to that page when I try to search.I also created the searchform.php.Here is my code for it:

```
 <form id="searchform" method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
     <input type="text" value="type your search"/>

</form>
```

What am I doing wrong?Do I have to activate the search page in functions.php?

Comment: Are you supposed to post the results to your blog URL, or the search.php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found the problem in the searchform I forgot to add a name="s" to the input so instead of :

```
<input type="text" value="type your search"/>
```

I should have had:

```
<input type="text" value="type your search" name="s"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

call `get_search_form();` in you're template to add the search functionality.

In search.php you can display the results.

Comment: I already added teh search form via widget the problem is when I try to search for something it points back to the homepage instead of search.php

Comment: try adding /?s=keyword to you're url. So www.website.nl/?s=keyword Do you get an search result?